# How to transfer two different UVs of one object to Substance Painter?

Tags: uv, export, import

I have two different UVs on one object. When I export FBX file from Blender to Substance Painter, I can see only one of them. I use UDIM tile workflow, another parts of the model have only one UV per object and work great. How can I use two UVs for one object in Substance?

[image: UVs]